# How to get data in python from ROS in real-time?

Tags: python, qt, ros

I am begginer in ROS and I don't understand how to do "publish" and "subscriber" in Python. I have a file .bag and I play this file with `rosbag play  "file.bag"`.

I get the values of topic with `rostopic echo /"topic"` or `rostopic echo -n 1 /"topic"` in a xterm.

However, I can't see this values in real time with python to show in a QT GUI. I have read the tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers but  I don't understand it.

Could I have a example with  `/odom [nav_msgs/Odometry]` or `/back_laser/filtered [sensor_msgs/LaserScan]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at the tutorials. Especially http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29

cd into youd source folder

and create new package:

```
catkin_create_pkg playground
```

cd in that directory

```
cd playground
```

create a file listener.py and and add following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
def callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id()+"I heard %s",data)

def listener():
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("odom", Odometry, callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

make executable:

```
chmod +x listener.py
```

start core:

```
roscore
```

new terminal, run listener node:

```
rosrun playground listener.py
```

new terminal publis some odometry data:

```
rostopic pub -r1 /odom nav_msgs/Odometry {}
```

Now you should see some output on your terminal where your listener was started!catki

Comment: Hi! Stephen,
I have tried this code. However, although /odom appears subscribe (rostopic list -v) I can't see anything in the xterm when I execute "listerner.py". What am I doing bad?

Thanks a lot and I am looking forward to hearing from you